# How to hyperlink across multiple tabs(worksheets)

Tags: excel

I have one excel it has 2 tabs

first tab has all data in column X(all are unique rows).
ex:
column X in first tab

```
Data:
A
B
C
D
```

in second tab column Z has few rows(these rows are just part of first tab data)
Ex:
Column Z in second tab

```
Data:
C
D
```

my requirement is , if I select row D(hyperlink) in second tab, I want to go to first tab automatically and display only D row

I am okay with either positioning at the selected one or filtered everything except selected in first tab.

I want to do this automatically instead of hard coding the destination cell for each row.since I have lot of data in both tabs.

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: you should take a look into programming with vba. See the `[excel-vba]`tag

Comment: I can't see your effort. FYI, SO does not provide code writing service. Please see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to achieve what your looking for is to use pivot tables. 
If you set your data up on a tab then create a pivot summary by variable name ( a,b, etc) on a second tab when you click on the second tab variable it will create a new sheet with just the data from variable a (i.e. the filtered data)